# Xcode Target Only builds to Mac?

Tags: ios, xcode, target, ios-app-extension

I have an Xcode project containing a "main app" and an app extension target.  Recently, and I don't know what I did to cause it, the app extension target only allows me to build to a mac.  [image: app extension target only shows a mac target option]

I have looked into the target, build settings, scheme and so on, and have no identified why this limitation has been imposed on me.  Recently, I have set up an Apple ID with this app to allow inter-app sharing via the NSUserDefaults group mechanism but I do not know if that has anything to do with this.  Here are some of my build settings.[image: build settings for app]

Further more, any googling or stacking about app extensions quickly leads to little to no information, so working on this project has been a bit of a pitiful endeavor as I'm very much on my own with any problems that crop up.  Hopefully, this issue is confined to general xcode development and not app extension specific issues.

Answer (score 0):

I recently encountered this issue with Xcode 13.1. After fiddling around a bit, Xcode crashed on me. When I reopened it, a popup showed up stating that Xcode needed to install command line developer tools. After selecting "Install", my issue went away and "iPhone" and "iPad" now show up as options in the "Deployment Info" section of Xcode again. So try installing the latest command line developer tools by opening the terminal and typing:

`xcode-select --install`